# Is there a way to add 1 to a string containing numbers in find and replace in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, replace, structural-search

I have code that looks like this:

public void testSomething1() {

}

public void testSomething2() {

}

public void testSomething3() {

}

And I want the result to look like this with find and replace:

public void testSomething2() {

}

public void testSomething3() {

}

public void testSomething4() {

}
I need this because I just realized I needed to add another test between 2 and 3 and leave the rest intact. I wish I could add it at the end, but I can't, I have to use this test generation tool and implement the tests for a school project. I have 51 tests and I don't want to shift n + 1 manually for ever test, especially since theres a comment referring to the number. Oh please tell me there's a way T_T. Thank you!

Comment: That could be a good prompt: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#delete-all-lines-that-have-the-id-attribute-greater-than-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Edit | Find | Replace Structurally` for this. Use a template like the following:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="Counting" text="void $method$();" recursive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="member" reformatAccordingToStyle="false" shortenFQN="false" replacement="void $replacement$();">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="method" regexp="(testSomething)(\d+)" within="" contains="" />
  <variableDefinition name="replacement" script="&quot;def (_,name, number) = (method.name =~ /(\p{L}+)(\d+)/)[0]&#10;name + (Integer.parseInt(number) + 1)&#10;&quot;" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

You can copy this pattern and use the `Import Template from Clipboard` action in the menu under the tool button of the Structural Search dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I had a feeling it had something to do with structures but had no idea where to start.